# Copy a Qtablewidget to word

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtablewidget

I'm a new user of Qt and I hope that you can help me. 
I want to copy a selected part of table from *Qtablewidget* to word file. 
How i can do that?
Thank you!

Comment: Show what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your selected cell get their data and use [ActiveX](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxobject.html) to communicate with Word file.

Comment: Thank you for your response!